# how to send a profile picture from loopback 4 to react native with user id and token

Tags: typescript, backend, loopback4

helllo everyone

#### i'm new in LoopBack 4

I create 2 endpoints API (i followed this example from official documentation LB4  [Upload and download files](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/File-upload-download.html)
 )

the 2 endpoints API works with several file types in backend , but the problem is i dont know how to post a file with a user id and token.

P.s :  upload and download file controllers are without model and repositories and the user controller is a REST Controller with CRUD functions.

**any suggestions guys ?**

Comment: You can use existing controller for image upload and create a field in user model to store its path.

Comment: i don't get your idea , can you please explain more ?

Comment: I am saying that you must have stored your image somewhere. So send the path of image to your frontend and display image using img tag.